# Multiplication Error in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, multiplication

```
Dim totinr As Double
totinr = 325.0 * 80.6
```

When i run above code (programatically using immediate window etc.) i got output like this `26194.999999` but manually or using calculator result come like this whole value `26195`. How this happen? how calculation perform in .NET for the above two value multiplication? only particular values multiplication is different in .NET otherwise 99% multiplication is correct

Comment: There are loads of questions like this, but they're not always easy to find. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx and http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx - they're from a C# perspective, but the basis is the same.

Comment: [`Double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx)

Comment: @UweKeim: That's almost certainly *not* a useful link, to be honest - especially with absolutely zero explanation.

Comment: @UweKeim: you're correct - but Ravi needs more background information (like "what is a 'Double', and how does it work?") before he can make use of "Double.Epsilon".  The C# In Depth articles cited by Jon Skeet and me are much more appropriate. IMHO...

Comment: Thanks to all i learned lot of things using above links

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important things you need to learn in programming - *any* language - is that floating point arithmetic is *an approximation*!

This is not a "bad thing", and it certainly shouldn't be a "surprising" thing.

Please read this link:

- [Binary Floating Point in .Net](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx)

Comment: Fun fact: Running this in Mathematica (which supports arbitrary precision) gives the value `26194.999999999996`. If you do this anywhere you'll get more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/618596/540339

It goes through the accuracy and when to use Float, Double or Decimal.